# Plant identification - starfish shape flowers

Tags: identification, flowers, tropical

Living condition:

- tropics with 25 - 35 degrees celsius
- very high humidity

Any suggestions? I have tried googling like mad and the nearest I have got is Pentas... Which I don't think it is.

[image: flowers 1]

[image: bud 1]

[image: leaf 1]

[image: plant 1]

Comment: I suspect its a member of the orchid family, but I can't find this exact one. There's an epiphytic orchid (Christmas Star Orchid) which is sort of similar, but yours definitely isn't that. If I come up with something,  I'll get back to this thread (definitely not Pentas!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try looking into Hoyas. I'm no expert but it looks to me like one of them.

Comment: I can see why you thought of Hoya,  but unfortunately, its not one of those either  - they're all vining in growth habit.

Comment: https://www.pinterest.com.au/pin/507569820497191919/

Comment: The above link shows shooting stars Hoya as the photo. And google shows Lorel C got it right! (https://garden.org/plants/view/87970/Shooting-Star-Hoya-Hoya-multiflora/)

Comment: @Yennie - I looked at Hoya, but never found a yellow one - and yours doesn't look like a vine, though it's described as one in the link, so its a new one on me, but  great flowers - are they fragrant? Oh,and I've just noticed the string its tied up with, missed that completely till now...